# I want to know the difference between :.0 and :.1f in format method

Tags: python-3.x, methods, format

In Python,

```
num_1 = 1
num_2 = 3
print("{} / {} = {:.0}".format(num_1, num_2, num_1 / num_2))
print("{} / {} = {:.1f}".format(num_1, num_2, num_1 / num_2))
print("{} / {} = {:.1}".format(num_1, num_2, num_1 / num_2))
```

The result of this code is:

```
1 / 3 = 0.3
1 / 3 = 0.3
1 / 3 = 0.3
```

Why are these results coming out?

Comment: Read through [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings)

Comment: I'm sorry but I try to read this site and I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I am at a loss to understand your question.  I will try to simplify the explanation previously cited.  The curly braces surround the replacement field and it's associated format specification.  So in your print statement you define three replacement fields.  The last of the three contains a format specification following the :.  This format specification defines the precision of the field to be displayed.  According to the cited document "The precision is a decimal number indicating how many digits should be displayed after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with 'f' and 'F', or before and after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with 'g' or 'G'."
In the first case, you have defined a field precision of :.0 but have not identified a type, therefore the precision is evaluated to be 1 position after the decimal point.  Since, the second defined field employs the :.1f precision, it also evaluates to a single decimal digit.  And the third is essentially the same as the first.  To illustrate this further:

```
num_1 = 1
num_2 = 3
print("{} / {} = {:.0f}".format(num_1, num_2, num_1 / num_2))
print("{} / {} = {:.1f}".format(num_1, num_2, num_1 / num_2))
print("{} / {} = {:.2f}".format(num_1, num_2, num_1 / num_2))
```

Yields:

```
1 / 3 = 0
1 / 3 = 0.3
1 / 3 = 0.33
```

Which illustrates the effect of including the type specifier.